# how to get data from spring controller without annotation

Tags: java, spring

i am using Spring 3.x for my MVC application without annotation. I want to get data only not view . I google it and found it is possible using  @ResponseBody . but i dont want to use annotation. how can i tell spring it is only data not a view without annotation. my sample code given below .

```
public class ShowGraphController extends AbstractController {

    private JdbcUserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao(JdbcUserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse responce) throws Exception {{
        return new  ModelAndView("want it retun as a data not a view name only");
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to use annotation ?

Comment: I also would like to know an answer for this question. Perhaps a link to a good tutorial

Comment: How is your Controller, defined as a controller, what request mapping does you method map to  ?

Comment: i am defining controller in dispatcher-servler.xml in <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/test">testController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>    and <bean name="testController" 
          class="ShowGraphController">
              <property name="userDao" ref="JdbcUserDao"/>
             
                 </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean JSON when you say data?

If you have to use ModelAndView style just handle the `HttpServletResponse` yourself and return `null`.

Comment: Use Jackson's `ObjectMapper.writeValue` and `HttpServletResponse.getPrintWriter()`

Answer (score 1):

It is bit convoluted as with Spring 3, you should ideally be using `ResponseBody` annotation. Have a look at this class [ResponseEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) , this may be useful for your purpose. Sample code from Spring doc :

```
@RequestMapping("/handle")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
  return new 
     ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use @ResponseBody, but if you do not want to use Annotation, you can populate response yourself:

```
protected void handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.getWriter().println("want it retun as a data not a view name only");
}
```